# Date/time limitation of posts where function must be executed

Tags: functions, date, code

I have this piece of function in my functions.php file:

```
function user_content_replace($content) {

$sentences_per_paragraph = 3; // settings

$pattern = '~(?<=[.?!…])\s+~'; // some punctuation and trailing space(s)

$sentences_array = preg_split($pattern, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // get sentences into array

$sentences_count = count($sentences_array); // count sentences

$output = ''; // new content init

// see PHP modulus
for($i = 0; $i < $sentences_count; $i++) {
    if($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i == 0) { //divisible by settings and is first
        $output .= "<p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // add paragraph and the first sentence
    } elseif($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i > 0) { //divisible by settings and not first
        $output .= "</p><p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // close and open paragraph, add the first sentence
    } else {
        $output .= $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // concatenate other sentences
    }
}

$output .= "</p>"; // close the last paragraph

echo $output;
}
add_filter('the_content','user_content_replace', 99);
```

This is just simple new-line random function on content (posts). Now my question is: Is there any way to restrict execution of this code on specific date range or to the range, for example:

Between date1 and date2 execute function, else - nothing (do not apply function on posts newer then date2) or simplier solution - just with one date:

All posts till date1 - execute function, else - do nothing.

Comment: Compare the [post date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) with your range and `add_filter()` only if condition is `true`.